# EC2 tomcat application keeps restarting after stopping

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 Application running tomcat 8 that can auto-scale 1-2 in a staging environment. When I log into AWS EC2 control panel ( right click on the instance I want to stop > select Instance State > Stop ) it stop the instance but fires up a new Instance.

**My Question**
Is it possible to stop the instance so that it doesn't create a new instance? if so how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If stopping the instance is causing the autoscaling group to fall below the minimum size you have defined, then autoscaling will create a new instance.

You can suspend this behavior: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_SuspendResume.html

Comment: 100% spot on, I just followed your link and Suspended Processes changed to `Launch`, stopped my instance and it didn't fire up a new instance. Thanks for quick response and I hope this helps others.